# Show that $\mathcal U$ is a contraction mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

I have 
$$
\mathcal U:\mathcal C([0,T],L^p(\mathbb R^d)) \rightarrow \mathcal C([0,T],L^p(\mathbb R^d))
$$

Linear such that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}||\mathcal U(h)(t)||_p^p\leq C_1\,||\mathcal U(h)(t)||_p^p + C_2\,||h(t)||_p^p
$$

I want to show that $\mathcal U$ is a contraction mapping (for appropriate choice of T). 
I think Grownwall lemma will work here, May be problem is too trivial but for some reason I cannot see it.

Regards

Harish

Comment: $C_i$ do not depend on $T$?

Comment: @user66081 yes $C_i$ do not depend on T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\|\mathcal U(h)(t)\|_p^p=\phi(t)$. Then 
$$
\phi'(t)\le C_1\phi(t)+C_2\,\|h(t)\|_p^p.
$$
From this
$$
\Bigl(e^{-C_1t}\phi(t)\Bigr)'\le C_2\,e^{-C_1t}\,\|h(t)\|_p^p.
$$
Integrating
$$
\phi(t)\le e^{C_1t}\,\phi(0)+C_2\,e^{C_1t}\int_0^t e^{-C_1s}\,\|h(s)\|_p^p\,ds\le C_2\,e^{C_1t}\int_0^t e^{-C_1s}\,\|h(s)\|_p^p\,ds.
$$
Then
$$
\sup_{0\le t\le T}\|\mathcal U(h)(t)\|_p^p\le \frac{C_2}{C_1}\,(e^{C_1T}-1)\sup_{0\le t\le T}\|h(t)\|_p^p.
$$

Comment: Please justify the last inequality in second last statement.i.e. why $$e^{c_1t}\phi (0)\leq 0$$

Comment: Somehow I supposed that $\mathcal{U}(h)$ was the difference of two solutions of a differential equation, or an equation of some type, which have the same initial condition, so that $\phi(0)=0$.